# Angular route component doesn't get updated destroyed and loaded again

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5, observable, ngrx

I got an issue with angular 2+ when a component is loaded then changed to another route, and then loaded again.

I got following code loading an array which then gets loaded in `ngFor`.

```
this.sub = this.subjectsService.getAllSubjects().subscribe(subjects => {
  this.subjects = subjects;
});
```

If I added an item on the first load, it gets loaded correctly but if I change to  another component and then go back, and then add an item, then the added value is not added to the list.

I've checked that the array is reset in subscribe but somehow angular just doesn't trigger html update. Any ideas of why this happens?

Comment: Are you adding items to subjects array?

Comment: Have you remembered to unsubscribe from this.sub before you leave the component?

Comment: Tried to unsubscribe. Doesn't help. And no, it's just an array of plain objects which are called subjects but that's not rxjs subjects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments above, you'll want to unsubscribe. Here's a quick example to help.

```
import { OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';


class XXXXXX implements OnDestroy {

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Comment: I said in the comment above that I've tried it. It doesn't help.

Comment: Oh, well that kind of helped. I just also needed to resubscribe on each edit of the list.

Comment: Ah yes, calling subscribe causes the observable to execute. The code you posted didn't give full context of how you were using it. Glad you got it figured out.